# compute CRC of struct in Python

Tags: python, struct, crc, pack, nrpe

I have the following struct, from the NRPE daemon code in C:

```
typedef struct packet_struct {
  int16_t packet_version;
  int16_t packet_type;
  uint32_t crc32_value;
  int16_t result_code;
  char buffer[1024];
} packet;
```

I want to send this data format to the C daemon from Python. The CRC is calculated when `crc32_value` is `0`, then it is put into the struct. My Python code to do this is as follows:

```
cmd = '_NRPE_CHECK'
pkt = struct.pack('hhIh1024s', 2, 1, 0, 0, cmd)
# pkt has length of 1034, as it should
checksum = zlib.crc32(pkt) & 0xFFFFFFFF
pkt = struct.pack('hhIh1024s', 2, 1, checksum, 0, cmd)
socket.send(....)
```

The daemon is receiving these values: `version=2  type=1  crc=FE4BBC49  result=0`

But it is calculating `crc=3731C3FD`

The actual C code to compute the CRC is:

https://github.com/KristianLyng/nrpe/blob/master/src/utils.c

and it is called via:

`calculate_crc32((char *)packet, sizeof(packet));`

When I ported those two functions to Python, I get the same as what `zlib.crc32` returns.

Is my `struct.pack` call correct? Why is my CRC computation differing from the server's?

Comment: Are you sure both platforms are using the same alignment?

Comment: I would believe so as the two numerical values in the front of the packed bytestring came out to be correct.

Comment: It could be a byte ordering problem. The server is probably using network (= big-endian) order but your script is using native since it doesn't specify anything at the beginning of the format string and override that default -- see [this](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) section of the online docs.

Comment: Possibilities: (1) endian differences (2) byte-swapping differences (3) padding [alignment] differences

Comment: @wberry: Aren't 1) and 2) basically the same thing?

Comment: Actually no.  In #1 you could read the same single byte as either 0xE2 or 0x47.  In #2 bytes could be stored as "UNIX" or "NUXI".

Comment: @wberry: _endianness_ usually means byte order. Your example #1 is commonly called [bit numbering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering) (although technically it could be called "bit endianness"). Regardless, the `struct` module only deals with byte streams -- but, fortunately, that's unlikely the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Python struct documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html):

> To handle platform-independent data formats or omit implicit pad
>   bytes, use standard size and alignment instead of native size and
>   alignment: see [Byte Order, Size, and Alignment](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#struct-alignment) for details.

Use '!' as the first format character to make the packed structure platform-independent.  It forces big-endian, standard type sizes, and no pad bytes.  Then the CRCs should be consistent.

Comment: Using '>' at the front got the Endianness correct, but for some reason I also had to add one bytes to the end. The size of that C-struct is 1036, not 1034; no idea why...

Comment: @sadris: It's likely padding the size of the C-struct up to the nearest whole 32-bits (4-bytes) native word size due to [C/C++ structure padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof#Structure_padding). Some compilers have an option to turn this on and off.

Comment: Just compare the 1034 bytes instead of trying to pad it to 1036 bytes.  The last two pad bytes of C structure are probably not initialized, so the padding you add won't match.  Unless you copy it from the C structure, which would just be silly.